# Check Value from DBI Query Without Consuming

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a table in my DB which I just added a new column to, and when I query this table in Perl I want to check only once if this field is empty or not. I need to check the value of this column in just the first row. Usually to go through the query results I use

```
while (my $row = $sthmm->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    # do stuff
}
```

I could check each row in the while loop but since I only need to do it once, I don't want to waste time doing that.

How can I retrieve one row and check the column's value without consuming it, meaning that I can still go through the whole result in the while loop after checking this condition.

Comment: Why aren't you querying directly for the result you need first?

Comment: Why check first?

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() )  {
   # Do stuff with first row

   do {
       # Do stuff to be done to each row
   } while $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
}
```

Comment: You might want to expand on why the bottom-driven loop (are they called that in English? I only know the German word, which is _fußgesteuerte Schleife_) is the right way to go here.

Comment: (We say top- and bottom-tested loop.) A top-tested loop will effectively start with the second row since we've already read the first row.